# How to construct a content type that would be useful for creating a "When is this store open" view

Tags: views, nodes

I would like to create an hours content type that could be attached to an individual location.  The goal is to create a page that a customer could visit to find which of the stores are open today, along with the times that they are open.  This would also reflect closures for holidays.

Comment: If it includes the dates that stores are open, it's not really just "hours" then, is it?  What kind of holiday closures are we talking about? (weekends, third Thursday of the month, etc.)

Comment: Like MLK Day, Memorial, Christmas, things like that.  The holidays are shared across 5 different schedules, with one location that is open on some of the holidays and not others.  The other 5 schedules, some are closed on certain days and some are open. The main reason I'd like to include hours is so that it has more complexity for things like adding events and reservable rooms down the road.  It will allow us to show intelligent defaults for customers.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've got a system managing alot of stores and open hours, it's probably easiest to just have a static "Page" with the store open hours on it. A basic page can be easily content managed.

Comment: True, but if we have a robust system we can do other things with it (like tie it in with an events system).  That's why I need to make it more complicated than a basic page.